# Forc portrait orientation on Create the activity

Tags: android, orientation, portrait

I'm Displaying a video in my application ..i want to force the activity to open in portrait mode , later the user can switch between orientation (Landscape and portrait ).

Can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You have several options to do that. I'll get you some examples..

Here is one programmatically:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
```

And with this you can set it in the manifest:

```
<activity 
android:name=".MyActivity" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"/>
```

But please search for similar questions next time, this question was asked many times before.

EDIT:

Just set

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

from the point you want the sensor to take over the setting again.

Comment: In this way it will always open in portrait mode..i just want it to open like this on creation,,then if the user change the orientation it can be Landscape or portrait.

Comment: Ok, see my edited answer. You'll need to change : android:screenOrientation="unspecified" instead of portrait I think.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Orientation extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //---change to landscape mode---
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}

To change to portrait mode, use the ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT constant:


        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might useful to you..

You can runtime force activity for specific orientation.

```
// For Landscpe        
myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


//For Portrait
myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

And later, you can switch to any of these two.